# Generalize the invertible stochastic matrices (Markov chain) as a group.

Tags: abstract-algebra, probability-theory

Define $\sum'(2, \mathbb R) = \{ \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix} \in GL_n (\mathbb R) : a + c = 1,\ b + d = 1 \}$.

Then clearly $\sum'(2, \mathbb R)$ with the matrix multiplication becomes a group.

(It can be shown by simple calculation.)

Now I want to generalize the result to $\sum'(3, \mathbb R)$ or $\sum'(n, \mathbb R)$ as a group. That is, show that it is a group with respect to the matrix multiplication.

Could anyone help me, by giving a hint? any idea?

Comment: The matrices in this group are not guaranteed to be stochastic, however. Their entries can be negative numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Denote by $J$ the $n\times n$ matrix having all its entries equal to $1$. Then $$\sum'(n, \mathbb R)=\{A\in\operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbb R): JA=J\}.$$ 
Now take $A,B\in\sum'(n, \mathbb R)$ and prove that $AB\in\sum'(n, \mathbb R)$: $J(AB)=(JA)B=JB=J$.

The associativity is okay, and $I_n\in\sum'(n, \mathbb R)$.

It remains to prove that $A\in\sum'(n, \mathbb R)$ $\Rightarrow$ $A^{-1}\in\sum'(n, \mathbb R)$: $JA=J$ $\Rightarrow$ $(JA)A^{-1}=JA^{-1}$ $\Rightarrow$ $J=JA^{-1}$.